Make expressions equal to 10 using exactly six 1s

You will use all six 1s.

You may use up to two subtraction symbols (no negation symbols).

You may use up to three decimal points without zeroes.

You will use one horizontal fraction bar (no "/").

You may concatenate digits including the decimal points.
Examples include:  11, 11.1, and .11 among the many types.

You may not use any grouping symbols.

You may not use any repeating decimals.

You may not use any factorial signs.

You may not use square roots or other roots.

You may not use exponentiation.

You may not use logarithms.

You may not use trigonometric functions.

You may not use any other numbers, characters, functions,
or operations.

This is in base ten.

The general  $ \ \dfrac{B - A}{D - C} \ $ form of a solution will not count as different
from
the general $ \ \dfrac{A - B}{C - D} \ $ form of a solution.


Try to create 13 essentially different solutions without the help of a computer program.


 $ 1.  \dfrac{111}{11.1}\ $   2.  $ \dfrac{11.1}{1.11}\ $  3.  $\dfrac{1.11}{.111}\ $  4.  $ \dfrac{111-1}{11}\ $  5.  $ \dfrac{11.1-1.1}{1}\ $  6.  $ \dfrac{1.11-.11}{.1}\ $  7.  $ \dfrac{1}{11.1-11}\ $  8.  $ \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1.1}\ $  9.  $ \dfrac{11.1-.1}{1.1}\ $  10.  $ \dfrac{11-1}{1.1-.1} $  11.  $ \dfrac{1.1-.1}{1.1-1}\ $  12.  $ \dfrac{1.1-1}{.11-.1}\ $  13.  $ \dfrac{1.1}{1.11-1}\ $  BONUS  14.   $ \dfrac{.11}{.111-.1}\ $


@ Donbhupi -- By not only completing the requested 13 solutions, but also by being thorough enough to get a bonus solution to (apparently) exhaust them, I hereby award you the title of Master of the Puzzle.  Thank you for your hard work and expertise.  Again, I would like to thank user ilikecorgis for all of his first-posted almost-complete solution.

Thank you to the community for looking at and/or attempting the puzzle.

Let's start with the obvious:

 $ \dfrac{111}{11.1}\  , \dfrac{11.1}{1.11}\ , \dfrac{1.11}{.111}\ $.

We can find another couple easy solutions by

 putting a lone $1$ in the denominator and making $10$ with the remaining five ones in the top: $11.1-1.1$. We can also divide everything through by 10 to get the two solutions: $ \dfrac{11.1-1.1}{1}\ $ and $ \dfrac{1.11-.11}{.1}\ $.

In reverse,

 if we put a 1 in the numerator we can use the five tens in the bottom to make $.1$: $11.1 - 11.$ Once again, we can divide everything through by 10 to get two more soultions: $ \dfrac{1}{11.1-11}\ $ and $ \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1.1}\ $.

We can continue in a similar vein:

 If we put 11 on the bottom, we can make 110 on the top with the remaining four ones: $111-1$. Dividing everything through by 10 once again gives us solutions eight and nine: $ \dfrac{111-1}{11}\ $ and $ \dfrac{11.1-.1}{1.1}\ $.

I next tried to

 move 11 to the numerator, but I couldn't find a good way to get 1.1 in the denominator, as subtracting from 11.1 would require 10 which we can't get without parentheses, and subtracting from 1.11 would require .01 which we also can't get.

So there's nine out of thirteen without even having to use the second subtraction. Once that is brought in,

 we can get two simple ways to make everything on the top just 10x everything on the bottom without having to complicate things: $ \dfrac{11-1}{1.1-.1}\ $ and $ \dfrac{1.1-1}{.11-.1}\ $.

And we can get twelve and thirteen by simply

 splitting the instances of $-1.1$ in $ \dfrac{11.1-1.1}{1}\ $ and $ \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1.1}\ $ into $-1-.1$, to get $ \dfrac{11.1-1-.1}{1}\ $ and $ \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1-.1}\ $.

So our final 13 solutions are:

 $ \dfrac{111}{11.1}\  , \dfrac{11.1}{1.11}\ , \dfrac{1.11}{.111}\ , \dfrac{11.1-1.1}{1}\ , \dfrac{1.11-.11}{.1}\ , \dfrac{1}{11.1-11}\ , \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1.1}\ , \dfrac{111-1}{11}\ , \dfrac{11.1-.1}{1.1}\ , \dfrac{11-1}{1.1-.1} , \dfrac{1.1-1}{.11-.1}\ , \dfrac{11.1-1-.1}{1}\ , \dfrac{.1}{1.11-1-.1}\ $


@ ilikecorgis -- You have a great effort, but your 13th solution is a variation on your 7th solution, and your 12th solution is a variation on your 4th solution, as you detailed in a prior box.  There are still two essentially different solutions remaining out of the ones I have worked out.

Update:  I am still waiting on 2 more essentially different solutions from any solvers to post here to finish off the puzzle.
